# Открыть урл, в браузере, из скрипта на андроиде

Tags: android, bash, webbrowser

Нужно открыть урл в браузере lightning из скрипта. Браузер я открываю следующим образом:

```
monkey -p  acr.browser.barebones -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```

На крайний случай сойдет и открыть урл в дефолтном браузере.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открыть урл в определенном браузере:

```
root@dolphin-fvd-p1:/opt/etc # cat OpenURL                                                                      
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/opt/sbin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:$PATH

am start --user 0 -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d $1 acr.browser.barebones
```

Просто открыть браузер:

```
root@dolphin-fvd-p1:/opt/etc # cat StartBrowser                                                                 
#!/bin/sh

PATH=/opt/sbin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:$PATH

am start --user 0  acr.browser.barebones
```